# Unable to target a class within a class in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to target a class within a class but it is having no effect.

My attempt:

```
<style>
.parentclass .childclass ul li a{
    color:red;
    background:black;
}    
</style>

<div class="parentclass">
    <ul class="childclass">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However if I target only the parent class it works just fine.

```
.parentclass ul li a{
    color:red;
    background:black;
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Here is a JSFiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/74Laypbq/

Comment: what you actually missed was the `>`(["parent operator" in css3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors))

Comment: read more about `css specificity` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Using it have pros and cons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSS:

```
.parentclass .childclass ul li a{
   color:red;
   background:black;
}
```

***What this actually means:*

select all links (`<a>`) under all list-item elements (`<li>`) under all unordered-list elements(`<ul>`) which comes under some element with class `.childclass` which ultimately belongs to some element with class `.parentclass`**.

The HTML:

```
<div class="parentclass">
    <ul class="childclass">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**The problem as you can see is that there is no element with class `.childclass` having the unordered-list element(`<ul>`).**

Instead there is a unordered-list element (`<ul>`) with class `.childclass`

ie. `<ul class="childclass">`

therefore the *correct way* is:

```
.parentclass ul.childclass li a{
   color:red;
   background:black;
 }
```

OR

```
.parentclass .childclass li a{
   color:red;
   background:black;
 }
```

OR

```
.parentclass ul li a{
   color:red;
   background:black;
 }
```

one of these may be more appropriate for your use, depending on what other classes and elements the rest of your html has and how they are structured. However all are correct ways.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
.parentclass ul.childclass li a
```

or even:

```
.parentclass ul li a
```

Answer (score 4):

You're targeting the `ul` as a child element of `.childclass`.  Try this:

```
.parentclass ul.childclass li a{
  color:red;
  background:black;
}
```

or just:

```
.parentclass .childclass li a{
  color:red;
  background:black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just take off the `ul` from `.parentclass .childclass ul li a` and it will work.

```css
.childclass li a {
    color: red;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentclass">
    <ul class="childclass">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Note:** I took off `.parentclass` from the code because there is only one instance of `.childclass` but you may need it if you have `.childclass` in other locations and you intend to style them differently.

Answer (score 1):

Your css needs to be

```
.parentclass  ul.childclass li a{
    color:red;
    background:black;
}
```

The `.childclass` is attached to the `ul`

With what you have, the DOM is looking for a tag before the `ul` with the class `childclass` such as:

```
<div class="parentclass">
  <div class="childclass">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

calling class `.childclass` is your `ul` already so do

```
.parentclass ul li a {
  color:red;
  background:black;
}
```

or

```
.parentclass .childclass li a {
  color:red;
  background:black;
}
```